# Cocos2d-x v4.0 crashing in iPhone Simulator with Xcode 12, Xcode 12.1, Xcode 12.2

Tags: c++, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Cocos2d-x v4.0 crashing in all iPhone Simulator. In device no crash

```
glslopt_shader* glslShader = glslopt_optimize(ctx, shaderType, source.c_str(), 0);
```

For above line everytime crashing. Not using any shader. Above line called by Sprite creation.

```
auto background = Sprite::create(TEX_MM_BG);
```

How to fix this crash for simulator ?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more details? Like stacktrace...

Comment: @Bernd you can see in screenshot, I called background = Sprite::create inside FWGMainMenu::setupBackground function, it crashed inside glslopt_optimize call...full function calls you can see in above image

Comment: @Bernd I thought above screenshot only xcode stacktrace, is there any other place you mean?

Comment: I can see some kind of stacktrace, true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that little info we can't help much.
But if I try to interpret the posted image corretly you receive a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" Exception.

This means more or less that you access a freed memory region or in general you try dereference a pointer pointing to an invalid memory address.

The only argument which could cause such an error is `source.c_str()`.
So you should check the code path of `source`.

In release builds you don't see always "access-after-free" because memory is not immediately released to the OS (which triggers such errors) it is just marked as "free" to allow faster allocations.

Comment: source.c_str() is not null, I just compared it with iPhone and simulator..both are same...crashing inside glslopt_optimize for simulator...other input to this api are not null. Strange..

Comment: I strongly guess crashing in old mac that not has Metal ? Mine 2015 mac book pro...not sure it support Metal or not.

Comment: Ah, right. This means the exception is not triggered at the line of the posted code. I simply mis interpreted the image. I assume there is a missing check somewhere.

Have you a chance to debug into ast_declarator_list::hir(exec_list*....

Comment: yes its something else problem in other place. Plain Cocos2d v4 project not crash for first background image. Thanks a lots for your answer.